# Paperclip and Amazon S3. Styled images can't be displayed, only downloaded. Original image is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Having some odd issues with paperclip, s3 and imagemagick.

The normal sized image will force an image download.

http://ads_honours_development.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/adverts/10/normal.jpg?1333899985

Meanwhile the original image is blank.

http://ads_honours_development.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/adverts/10/original.jpg?1333899985

Here is the model.

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :group

 #paperclip

 has_attached_file :photo, {
:styles => { :large => "512x512", :normal => "360x360", :small => "200x200", :tiny => "64x64", :thumbnail => "32x32" },
:convert_options => { :large => "-quality 86" },
:default_url => "/images/thumbnail/blank-recipe.png",
:url => ':s3_domain_url',
:path => 'assets/:class/:id/:style.:extension',
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
:s3_permissions => 'public-read',
:s3_protocol => 'http'}

validates_attachment_presence :photo
end
```

Gem file is like:

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.0'
```

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help/suggestions?

**UPDATE** I've got this running on heroku as well and the exact same issue occurs, so it's not down to my development machines settings. I'm guessing the problem lies within Paperclip itself, my bucket setup or the amazon aws-sdk gem.

**SECOND UPDATE** Ok so all of these images load in IE, but not Chrome. What gives?

Comment: This version of paperclip is very old, please try to upgrade and see if the problem goes away: gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"

Comment: It's updated to use 2.7.0. I get a different problem using 3.0. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/751 So it doesn't seem to be related to the paperclip version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have an extension running on chrome which is blocking the images? The link shows for me in Chrome only with adblock disabled.

Comment: Ah such an obvious answer, "advert" in the image path seems to have been confusing adblock. Annoying. Cheers!